# Rails app won't delete user account using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to create a prelaunch signup page from the RailsApps Project template: http://railsapps.github.com/rails-prelaunch-signup/

I've deployed it to Heroku and the basic site works fine. You can go to it here: http://arcane-lake-2098.herokuapp.com

The problem is a user can't delete his/her account using the following code in  app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb

```
<p>Unhappy? <%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete %>.</p>
```

Everything else works fine (create account, edit name, password etc..) - but when I click "Cancel my account" and then click "OK" in the popup window it says "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

I'm using rails 3.2.8

I've hunted through all the Q&A's and most other people seem to have an issue with the route path.

Here are the logs from the error:

```
2012-10-11T09:46:49+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 49.2.27.159 at 2012-10-11 09:46:49 +0000
2012-10-11T09:46:49+00:00 heroku[router]: POST arcane-lake-2098.herokuapp.com/users/sign_in dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=118ms status=302 bytes=104
2012-10-11T09:46:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-11T09:46:49+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 49.2.27.159 at 2012-10-11 09:46:49 +0000
2012-10-11T09:46:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-11T09:46:49+00:00 heroku[router]: GET arcane-lake-2098.herokuapp.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=1521
2012-10-11T09:46:51+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-11T09:46:51+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-11T09:46:51+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/edit" for 49.2.27.159 at 2012-10-11 09:46:51 +0000
2012-10-11T09:46:51+00:00 heroku[router]: GET arcane-lake-2098.herokuapp.com/users/edit dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=15ms status=200 bytes=2949
2012-10-11T09:46:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-11T09:46:56+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-11T09:46:56+00:00 app[web.1]: Started DELETE "/users" for 49.2.27.159 at 2012-10-11 09:46:56 +0000
2012-10-11T09:46:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-11T09:46:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-11T09:46:57+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-10-11T09:46:57+00:00 app[web.1]: Hominid::APIError (<232> There is no record of "wheresclark@gmail.com" in the database):
2012-10-11T09:46:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user.rb:69:in `remove_user_from_mailchimp'
2012-10-11T09:46:57+00:00 heroku[router]: POST arcane-lake-2098.herokuapp.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=436ms status=500 bytes=643
```

Feel free to sign up and try cancelling your account to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means app throws 500 status code. You need to look 
[at your logs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval) and then search for precise error.

**UPDATE 1**

As error says in app/models/user.rb line 69 there's attempt to find user with email "wheresclark@gmail.com". As I understand it access remote database with HominidAPI. You probably just missing here existence check, can't say for sure since there's no code for it(and it's probably context specific). I think user is deleted before this method executes and this is causes problem.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my post above to include the logs. It looks like it's something to do with the database. I'm still able to add users and modify accounts though which is strange.

Comment: Thanks Vadim. I'll have a tinker with the HomonidAPI and see if I can resolve it that way.